# NSScanner to NSArray input calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to be able to tokenize an input string into an array (or some efficient method, open to suggestions) which would allow me to easily interpret and alter the given input.

For example, let's say we're dealing with a calculator, and the input is

```
  55+63.7/7-(6+5)/9+(3-6.5)/(5-2)
```

I need to create an array or a series of tokens that would be like

```
 {"55","+","63.7","/","7","-","(","6","+","5","... }
```

Best practices? I've tried looking into parseKit and NSScanner, and both seem very plausible, but I'd like an example, if possible, to truncate the time required to get this thing working properly.

EDIT:

Essentially what I'm looking for is simple set of 'parser' logic...

If I were to build a full parser/scanner myself I could, with the psuedo code like

```
 char c
 NSMutableString temp
 NSMutableArray parsed 
 For each c in input {
    if is_number(c)
       while is_number(c)
          add c to temp
       parsed addObject:temp
       reset temp
    if is_operation(c) //single character operations like +, -, /, 
       add c to temp 
       parsed addObject:temp
       reset temp
    if is_letter(c)
       while is_letter(c)
          add c to temp
       if is_keyword(temp) //like sin, cos, tan
           parsed addObject:temp
       else
           input misunderstood //not necessary, really, just useful
       reset temp
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the examples on the parsekit homepage?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Please be more precise about what information you need to enable you to make a decision.

Comment: @CarlNorum I'd prefer to not have to download a third party application to get this done... I was hoping NSScanner would be sufficient, or another option that doesn't require adding nine frameworks that I don't know for certain will be supported permanently...

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm asking to parse an input string into a series of tokens that is held in an array (or linked list, or any connected body)

Comment: Sure, I got that, but there's a fair bit of sample code available from Apple, in the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html), and linked from the [NSScanner Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). What, specifically, are you hung up on?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Fair enough, and I don't intend for other players on stack overflow to do that research for me... It's just that form my understanding of the man pages NSScanner seems to be limited to breaking apart an input based upon some given rule (space, colon, etc) or set of rules, but isn't intelligent enough to actually understand when the content changes... like from text to "+", etc.

I know I can just write this myself... just go through character by character, and that's fine, I was just basically polling, hoping, there was a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm not trying to shut you down, just to figure out what you need. What you just wrote is much more specific than what's in your question, and I think a little something in that line would help you get an answer if you edit it in. Although I still don't understand what you mean by "content changes from text to '+'", since a '+' would be part of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right. What you want top build is a simple recursive decent parser. I just created a Bencoding parser which is as simple as it can get. Maybe you can get a couple of ideas

https://github.com/mmick66/KDBencoding